# Connect two computers to a Server

Tags: networking, home-networking, network-adapter

I have a computer and its Motherboard has two LAN Ports like in this image:

[image]

I have two other computers that I would like to connect to this computer.
How should i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Internet connection is not important, all you need is a pair of crossover UTP cable. Then, connect server with the client PC's, and configure IP's on every host. Simplest way, is to go with something like

- 10.0.0.1 for server
- 10.0.0.2 for PC1
- 10.0.0.3 for PC2

For such network, mask is not very important, but you must use max. 29 bit mask (255.255.255.248). This mask MUST be the same on every host (both server and clients). 
You don't need to set up default gateway nor DNS servers.

And done.

Comment: thanks for helping
but server has two Ethernet port
i should assign 10.0.0.1 for both of them?

Comment: Damn, right. Each interface must have its own IP address, so on server i.e. eth0 - 10.0.0.1, eth1 - 10.0.0.2

Comment: is important to use crossOver cable?

Comment: It depends on cards installed on your device. If they support auto mdi(x), it's not necessary to use crossover. If not, simple, straight-through cable won't even work. Best way to check this, is to connect two of these computers with a straight-through cable. When LED's won't even blink - you need crossover. ;)

Comment: i do this works and use crossOver cable between server and pc1 and get ping very well

but between server and pc2  used a Lan cable. after that i ping from server to pc2 and seys Unreachanle, while the LED`s where blinking!!!

Comment: I'd recommend using a hub or switch, if you want each computer to be able to talk to the other.

Comment: Well, that's odd, they blink all the time? They shouldn't as there is no electric circuit... Although try to connect them with the crossover cable, and then ping.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this computer connected to the internet then you will have to connect all three up to a switch, if the server, or other device on the networkm is acting as a DHCP then they will pick up addresses from that, if not you will have to assign them.

You could also mess about connecting the LAN ports of the 3 PC's with ethernet cables (Might have to be crossover cables depending on the NIC's available) Set the IP addresses into a correct range and they should all be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Easiest is the router/switch, which you can pick up from a store.  Or get one used from Craigslist for practically nothing.

Comment: No. internet is not important.

Comment: I want just connect thise clients to this server and i request you for say step by step

Comment: For step-by-step, we're gonna need to know the Operating Systems on the server and the two other computers

Comment: i want know about networking steps.

Comment: be shre that i can handle my open suse :)

Comment: @Milad Sobhkhiz 1. Buy an ethernet switch and 3 ethernet cables. 2. Power on the switch. 3. Connect each of the 3 cables to the switch, and the other ends of the cables into your 3 PCs.

Comment: @nos - He will also need to set all interfaces to the correct IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set interfaces to correct addresses unless you are using a Server Operating System which has default IP addressing TURNED OFF.  By default, workstation operating systems - Linux, OSX, Windows, have default IP addressing TURNED ON. (and it's been that way for many years now). EVEN IF THERE IS NO DHCP MODEM/ROUTER, workstations by default will all choose interoperable IP addresses and subnet.